# Flutter app crashes (internal testing google play store) but local apk works

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-test

When I install the **local apk** or debugged version it works fine **(My project is in release mode)**but when I upload the **app-release apk on google play store** (Internet Testing) and download the app experience crashes and does not start.

```
Note: C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\geocoding-2.0.0\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\geocoding\GeocodingPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.                    
Note: C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_maps_flutter-2.0.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\googlemaps\Convert.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.                    
Note: C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_maps_flutter-2.0.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\googlemaps\TileProviderController.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

The last build was all okay but failed even local testing

```
PS C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\mobile-app-master> flutter build apk

Building without sound null safety
For more information see https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                                
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                     139.2s
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-release.apk (39.2MB).
PS C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\mobile-app-master> flutter install
Installing app.apk to vivo 1906...
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
```

Both the app-release.apk worked nor app.apk crashed when I installed it on my phone or uploaded on play store.

Comment: Do you have any log of the crash?

Comment: No it's a build APK when I click it opens and quits

Comment: I think the error can be caused vivo phone. Could you try another model?

Comment: I tried other phone as well though

Comment: facing same issue did you get the reason for it.